# Json to jquery bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, charts

I'm trying to fill data from json to bar chart. I'm using [that chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-example-usage) and this is its datastructure:

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]};
```

but I have different json format:

```
var data = {
            resultDescription: "SUCCESS",
            data: [ ["JAN","1048729"], ["FEB","1220608"],["MAR","1299965"],["APR","1288644"],["MAY","1077342"],["JUN","705690"],["JUL","666131"],["AUG","769444"],["SEP","581618"],["OCT","564438"],["NOV","535066"],["DEC","1241228"]]};
```

So I thought If I'll change that format to similar format of that chart it will work and for that I've divided that 2d Array within 2 1d array and then Array structure like that json.
[JSFIDDLE example which logs that array in console](http://jsfiddle.net/r3k38d3j/6/)

**BUT** it logs in console as well

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = {
            resultDescription: "SUCCESS",
            data: [["JAN","1048729"],["FEB","1220608"],["MAR","1299965"],["APR","1288644"],["MAY","1077342"],["JUN","705690"],["JUL","666131"],["AUG","769444"],["SEP","581618"],["OCT","564438"],["NOV","535066"],["DEC","1241228"]]};
var labelsArr = [];
var dataArr = [];

$.each(data.data,function(i,v){
    labelsArr.push(v[0]);
    dataArr.push(v[1]);
});

var datas = {
    labels: labelsArr,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: dataArr
        },
    ]
};
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ctx = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(datas);
    }, 1500);
```

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/r3k38d3j/9/

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you can clean up your code quite a bit, but just to make it work, you should change your mapped data to this:

```
var mappedData = {labels: labelsArr, datasets: [{ data:dataArr} ]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map your source object to the destination object like this:

```
var output = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    data: []
  }]
};

data.data.map(function(dataPoint, index) {
  output.labels.push(dataPoint[0]);
  output.datasets[0].data.push(dataPoint[1]);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3k38d3j/8/